# Mouseover on questions show a horizontal rule

Tags: bug, design

When hovering over questions on the front page (either on the main page or on meta), there is an underline associated with the hyperlink that extends across the entire question block (when viewed under Chrome 47.0.2526.106 m):

[image]

Here's the same view under Firefox (43.0.1) where the underline only spans the question title width:

[image]

This does not appear to be the case with other sites on the network (tested on [Meta.SE](http://meta.stackexchange.com) and [SO](http://stackoverflow.com)).

Comment: I can see the underline also in Math.SE, both with Safari and Firefox, but not on Italian.SE

Comment: I can confirm that the line is correctly limited by the length of the title  with FF42 on Linux (OpenSuSE 13.2)

Comment: It is also correctly limited with Chrome 47.0.2526.106 on my OSX 10.11.2